# JQuery Mobile automatically open URL in new tab

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a function to open an URL automatically after some seconds.
What i have tried until now (that is now working in my android browser and chrome) is the code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      setTimeout(function() { 
       'window.open("http://google.com")', 2000); 
  });
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Fix your syntax and it will work! Check the console before posting questions, that should have given you an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` call isn't quite right - you're actually just declaring a string and a number, then doing nothing with them. Change it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.open("http://google.com");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Secondly, see the docs for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open): It accepts a second parameter, which determines the name of the window to open. If you set this to `_blank`, you're telling the browser to open a new window (or tab) rather than replace the current page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
    }, 2000);
});
```

However, you *might* run into trouble with the browser's popup blocker. Generally, opening a new window or tab should be initiated after a `click` event.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, your setTimeout call is broken:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() { 
       window.open("http://google.com"); 
    }, 2000);
});
```